# iOS Browser Access Sandbox File

Tags: javascript, ios, browser, sandbox

I have an HTML/Javascript application which I would like to use on an iPad.  The app accesses a fairly large datafile.  I installed Mercury, which allows me to move the datafile into its sandbox, but <input type='file'> only looks in the photo store.

Is there an iPad browser app that allows <input type='file'> access to sandboxed files?

Answer (score 0):

No as there is nothing like a file selector or open panel in iOS at all.